# Why are incircle and circumcircle of regular polygons concentric?

Tags: geometry

Do the incircle and the circumcircle of a regular polygon have to be concentrical? Why? Can't there be an irregular polygon with that property?

Comment: A regular polygon has a definite centre. So does a rectangle.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the circumcircle of a rectangle is. In any event, I don't think it's unique, so while I think the incircle and the circumcircle of a rectangle *can* be concentric, I don't think they have to be.

Comment: Maybe a rhombus works better. The incircle and circumcircle are unique, and concentric.

Comment: Any thoughts, Vmimi?

Comment: Well, I thought that that the concepto of incircle and circumcircle didn't Just apply to triangles

Comment: By incircle I referí to a circle that touches in one point all the sides of the regular polygon and by circumcircle I refer to a circle that goes through all the vértices of the polygon

Comment: For regular polygons, there is no difficulty. But for irregular polygons, there is, in general, no circle that touches all sides in one point, and no circle that goes through all vertices. So I made up a definition, and used it to write an answer, and you have had nothing to say about that answer. There's also my comment about the rhombus.

Comment: Well, but my main question is why the incircle and the circumcircle of a regular polygon have to be concentrical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by incircle and circumcircle, if the polygon is irregular. I'll take it to mean the largest circle contained in, and the smallest circle containing, the polygon.

Start with an equilateral triangle, $T$. Draw a tiny triangle with one side sitting on a side of $T$, the opposite vertex being outside $T$. The union of the two triangles is an irregular pentagon or hexagon (it's also not convex, but nothing in the problem statement insisted on convex polygons), call it $U$. The incircle of $T$ is still the incircle of $U$, and the circumcircle of $T$ is still the circumcircle of $U$, so $U$ is an irregular polygon with the required property.

EDIT: Now to answer the question about regular polygons. Let $C$ be the center of the circumcircle of the regular polygon $P$. Draw line segments joining $C$ to each of the vertices of $P$. This cuts $P$ up into congruent triangles. In each of these triangles, draw an altitude from $C$ to the side opposite (which is a side of $P$). These altitudes must all have the same length (since the triangles are all congruent), so a circle centered at $C$ with that length as radius will be tangent to each side; it will be the inscribed circle.

Comment: It makes sense but then can a regular polygon have $2$ different circumcircles?.

Comment: Of course not. Pick a vertex, draw the line segments joining that vertex to each of the other vertices; the circumcenter must lie on the perpendicular bisector of each of those line segments; any two of those bisectors can only intersect at one point.

Comment: You have two answers now. Your thoughts?

Comment: Are you still here, Vmimi?

Comment: Yes, and what about incircles? Can a polygon have two different incircles?

Comment: No. Consider any two adjacent sides of the regular polygon. To be the same distance from each of these two sides, the center of the incircle must be on the bisector of the angle between the two sides. So it must be on the bisector of each of the angles between sides. But any two of these bisectors meet at just one point, so there's just one incircle.

Comment: Better now, Vmimi?

Comment: Yes, that´s enough.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to upvote any answers you found helpful, and to "accept" one of the answers, by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: You could do that today, Vmimi.

Comment: I had already upvoted yours.

Comment: Good. You still have the option of "accepting an answer" by clicking in the check mark next to it. If you're not keen to accept either answer, you could explain what's unsatisfactory about them, what more you need.

Answer (score 1):

A regular polygon of $n$ sides can be rotated by $360/n$ degrees and result in the same polygon. 
Since the circumcircle passes through three or more vertices of the polygon, since the circumcircle after rotation must still pass through those same points,
and since three points determine a circle,
we have the same circumcircle after rotation as before.

If the circumcircle and incircle are not concentric, then this rotation will move the center of at least one of those circles.
Since the circumcircle cannot change, the incircle must have been the one moved.
So now we have a new incircle of the regular polygon.
In this way we could obtain at least $n$ different versions of the incircle.
Does a polygon of $n$ sides have $n$ distinct incircles?

In fact, using Gerry Myerson's construction, we can show that the incircle must be tangent to the circle at the midpoint of each side and is uniquely determined by this. This is only possible if it is concentric with the circumcircle.

Conversely, consider two concentric circles. If the definition of incircle is that it is tangent to every side of the polygon, and the definition of circumcircle is that it passes through every vertex, then the only kind of side a polygon can have with this incircle and this circumcircle is a segment with both ends on the circumcircle, tangent to the incircle at the segment's midpoint. By symmetry of the circles, every such segment has the same length, and if two such segments share an endpoint (a vertex of the would-be polygon) then the angle between them is always the same as any other two sides meeting at a vertex.

So we construct one such side arbitrarily, then construct another side sharing one of the endpoints of the first side, then a third side sharing an endpoint of the second side, and so forth around the circles. After some number of sides, either the last side constructed meets the first side at a vertex, forming a regular polygon,
or we construct a side that crosses the first side, and the best we can hope for is that if we continue we will eventually get a star.
The only polygons with concentric incircles and circumcircles (by this strict definition of those circles) are regular polygons and regular stars.